# Segmentation fault: 11; range-based for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a small programming exercise in C++. Goal is to initiate an array with the first 32 exponentations of 2 and to output them afterwards.
Using a normal for loop there's no problem but I tried to use the range-based for loop introduced in the C++11 standard.
During compilation I get the warning "range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]".
Running the program I get the error "Segmentation fault: 11" without any further output.

I got already that the elem variable somehow is broken but I don't know how.
Hope you can help a n00b :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int LAENGE = 32;
    long potenzen[LAENGE];

    for(int elem : potenzen)
    {
        potenzen[elem] = pow(2.0, (double) (elem + 1));
    }

    for(int elem : potenzen)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << potenzen[elem];
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From the looks of how you use the foreach loop, I guess youre used to writing javascript :)

Comment: Haha, I wish! I'm completely new to programming and just wanted to try out the new C++ standard :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`elem` is assigned the **values** in `potenzen`, not indices. `cout << elem;` is what you want instead to print the elements of the array. And in order to fill the array, simply use integer indices:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) { // ProTip #1: use English identifiers
    array[i] = 2 << i; // ProTip #2: don't use `pow()` when working with integers
}
```

As to the compiler warning: use the `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` flag when compiling to tell the compiler you are intending to use C++11 features (assuming you use GCC or clang -- I'm not sure about other compilers.)

Comment: It was entertaining watching this go from 4 or 5 answers down to just two. Anyway, +1 for catching all the issues!

Comment: @Cornstalks Yeah... some answers were initially wrong, some of them have been fixed, some of them have been deleted. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help!
Using the normal loop I got it working priorly but I thought learning/using the new standard might be useful too :)
Accepted the answer of Nemanja still, just because you already have such a high reputation but of course yours was just as helpful :P

Comment: Hey I got a another follow up question: how does this << operator work? I find nothing about it and somehow in another exercise I did, it didn't work out the way I expected it to do. Isn't "2 << 5" just "2 to the power of 5"?

Comment: @Zuup The `<<` operator is overloaded. For integer types, `a << b` means "`a` shifted to the left by `b` binary places", i. e. `a * 2 to the bth power`. Standard stream classes, however, override it so it acts as a stream appending operator, i. e. `std::cout << foo` writes `foo` to the standard output.

Comment: @H2CO3 Ah thanks! I was familiar with its function in streaming but the other operation seems useful too. So your tip regarding not using pow with integers is confined to powers to the base of 2 right?

Comment: @Zuup No, it still stands for any base and exponent if you are operating on integers. You certainly can't raise 3 to the 4th power easily by doing a bitwise shift, but this still doesn't mean that you should use `pow(3, 4)`. Writing a simple integer power function (one which just does repeated multiplication) isn't hard and it will then be guaranteed to give correct results (not to mention that it can be faster, and sometimes that counts.)

Answer (score 3):

Ranged for loop wil give you element values, and not the element indices.

```
    potenzen[elem] = pow(2.0, (double) (elem + 1));
```

should be

```
for(int i = 0; i < LAENGE; i++)
  potenzen[i] = 2 << i;
```

(For shifting, refer to the H2CO3's answer and to the his comments below)

Note that you can't use foreach loop here:

```
for(int& elem : potenzen)
{
    elem = pow(2.0, (double) (elem + 1));
}
```

as you're accessing not-initialized value of `elem` in the right side of the statement.

Also:

```
for(int elem : potenzen)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << potenzen[elem];
}
```

Should be

```
for(int elem : potenzen)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << elem;
}
```

as `elem` will contain array values.

Comment: @H2CO3 because he just want to get 2^(i+1) with integers?

Comment: Exactly. And `pow()` operates on `double`s, and as we know, floating-point operations are not exact, thus they're unreliable. Maybe he will get the sequence `1 3 7 15` etc...

Comment: Also, that should be either `2 << i` or `1 << (i + 1)` but certianly not `2 << (i + 1)`. The former would be the solution if he wanted `pow(4, i)`.

Comment: Now you answer's perfect!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!
Misinterpreted the range-based loop completely :P

Comment: @Zuup Thanks! But, you should really accept H2CO3's answer, as he helped me a lot making this answer worth!

Answer (score 1):

The above answers rightly point out the issues in your code, however if you want to have array indices as element values you've to set them up, without which they'd be initialized to indeterminate (garbage) values; the following code is also a solution that's somewhat similar to what you tried to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  constexpr auto count = 32;
  unsigned long long values[count] = { }; // initialise elements to 0
  auto i = 0;
  // fill them with their respective index values
  std::generate_n(values, count, [&i] { return i++; });
  for(auto &x : values)
  {
    // without casting the literal 2 would be treated as an int
    x = static_cast<unsigned long long>(2) << x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I've used `unsigned long long` instead of `long`, since on many systems the size of a long is 4 bytes, but 2^32 = 4294967296 = 0x100000000 I.e. 33 bits are required. Also since we know that all values are going to be positive, making it unsigned makes more sense.